# Problems overloading operator "=" in template

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have this code from a sequence class from an earlier assignment, and am supposed to convert it into a template with a node class. All of my other functions seem to work fine, but there seems to be something wrong with the wording or semantics of this overloaded operator. Here is my code:

```
template <class sequence, class Item>
void operator =(const sequence source)
{

if (this == &source)

{

    return;

}

list_clear(head_ptr);

many_nodes = 0;

list_copy(source.head_ptr, head_ptr, tail_ptr);

start();

for (node *ptr=source.head_ptr; ptr != source.cursor; ptr = ptr->link())

{

    advance();

}

many_nodes = source.many_nodes;

}
```

This is the error I'm getting: 6\sequence4.template(152): error C2801: 'main_savitch_6B::operator =' must be a non-static member

Line 152 is the closing brace of the function.

I did search the site for answers and tried some fixes, but none seemed to work.

Thanks guys, I appreciate all the help!

Comment: It is not apparent from the posted snippet whether `operator =` is indeed a non-static member function of some class.

Comment: is the definition inside the class declaration? show the whole code. and indent it please.

Comment: and template parameter `Item` cannot be inferenced implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

I think the signature of your operator= is not correct. I think normally you must have something like this:

```
Sequence & operator=(const Sequence & rhs){
if (&rhs != this){
// Your stuff ...
}
return *this;
}
```

Comment: Or `Sequence& Sequence::operator=(const Sequence & rhs)`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've been asked to create a class `Sequence`, templated on `Item` and the class `Sequence` has an assignment operator. In which case the syntax would be.

```
template< class Item >
class Sequence
{
    Sequence& operator=( Sequence const& rhs )
    {
        ...
    }
...
};
```

Or I may have misunderstood the question.